# Как подключить bootstrap 4 к VisualStudio ASP.NET Core 2.0 React Template?

Tags: visual-studio, bootstrap, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2017

Использую `ASP.NET Core 2.0 React Template` и хочу к нему подключить `bootstrap 4`. Установил соответствующий `npm` пакет `bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2`, но не понимаю как его подключить к проекту.

Ругается:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

С `bootstrap 3.3.7` всё работало нормально. Пакет подключался через `import 'bootstrap';` в `boot.tsx` файле.

Comment: не подключена jquery

Comment: @kizoso , да я так и подумал, но не понимаю как её подключить, она тоже инсталлирована через `npm`... и для bootstrap 3.3.7 который тоже требует `jquery` всё работало прекрасно. По идее её должен `webpack` подхватывать что в проекте...

Comment: npm install jquery

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: Спасибо, надо было сделать `import 'jquery';`